# What does `:-` mean in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, parameter

I saw this in the end of an awesome shell script but I can't understand the logic here because I think it's being short-handed for a longer command.

```
spark ${@:-`cat`}
```

This apears at the end of [this script](https://github.com/holman/spark/blob/master/spark). Any ideas?

+ Marks for some one who extends it into a full segment of code, even if its slower (Better for explanation)

Comment: The question which already has answer doesn't have explanation for `@` which is what this question is about. This is definitely _not_ duplicate question

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's the first special case of parameter substitution in `man bash`:

> `${parameter:-word}`
>       Use  Default  Values.  If `parameter` is unset or null, the expansion of `word` is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of  `parameter` is substituted.

In the case you mentioned, either the user has provided arguments on the command line and they will be used, or the user is asked to input them on standard input afterwards.

Comment: What does it means when `parameter` is `@` ?

Answer (score 5):

Afaik `:-` is basically: use `$@` OR `` `cat` `` ( without setting `$@` to `` `cat` `` )...

so some variable substition thingy...

Edit: So it gives you some sort of interactive input...

Here's a little Terminal test:

```
localhost:~ _druu$ echo ${@:-`cat`}
hello
world
;)
^\hello world ;)
localhost:~ _druu$
```