# Meaning of ":-" in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash code `export TM_SCALAC=${TM_SCALAC:-scalac}`.

I'm not sure the meaning of ":-" inside the `${}`.
How do I interpret this line of bash code?

Comment: Related: [What does `:-` mean in a shell script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30470/what-does-mean-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That means if `TM_SCALAC` isn't already set, set it to "`scalac`".

> From bash [reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):
>
> 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion
>
> ...
>
> ${parameter:-word} If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of
>   word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.