# What does this line in bash do? Parameter-||scriptname

Tags: bash, shell-script, parameter

I've been reading through the `bash` man page, and reading through scripts on my system (CentOS 6.7), looking up things in the `bash` man page as I go.  It's a great exercise; I learned, for instance, how `/etc/profile` checks if the `-i` option is set when there are actually no options in the positional parameters (so `getopts` wouldn't work).

However, the following line has me totally stumped; I can't find anything in the `bash` man page that explains what it could be doing:

```
LESSOPEN="${LESSOPEN-||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s}"
```

(This is a portion of a line in `/etc/profile.d/less.sh`.)

Am I just missing something in `man bash`?

---

Yes, I *was* missing something in `man bash`: Above the explanation for `${parameter:-word}`, it says `Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset.`  This was the missing piece.  (And is not covered in the "possible duplicate" question, by the way.)

The fact that the default value being assigned was the name of a script after an "or" operator only added to my confusion!  :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \`:-\` mean in a shell script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30470/what-does-mean-in-a-shell-script)

Comment: Also related, the meaning of `||commandname %s` in the `LESSOPEN` environment variable can be read about at `LESS='+/^INPUT PREPROCESSOR' man less`.  As I learned when researching https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396400/135943.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not `bash` specific but it existed in the Bourne Shell since 1976.

Check the Bourne Shell man page:

http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html

Check section **Parameter Substitution** currently starting on page 7.

```
${parameter-word}        Use Default Values. If parameter is unset,
                         the  expansion  of  word is substituted;
                         otherwise,  the  value of parameter is substituted.
```

For a complete overview, there is:

> ```
>                      | parameter nonnull | parameter null  | parameter unset
>   ___________________|___________________|_________________|________________
>   ${parameter:-word} | subst. parameter  | subst. word     | subst. word
>   ___________________|___________________|_________________|________________
>   ${parameter-word}  | subst. parameter  | subst. null     | subst. word
>   ___________________|___________________|_________________|________________
>   ${parameter:=word} | subst. parameter  | assign word     | assign word
>   ___________________|___________________|_________________|________________
>   ${parameter=word}  | subst. parameter  | subst. null     | assign word
>   ___________________|___________________|_________________|________________
>   ${parameter:?word} | subst. parameter  | error, exit     | error, exit
>   ___________________|___________________|_________________|________________
>   ${parameter?word}  | subst. parameter  | subst. null     | error, exit
>   ___________________|___________________|_________________|________________
>   ${parameter:+word} | subst. word       | subst. null     | subst. null
>   ___________________|___________________|_________________|________________
>   ${parameter+word}  | subst. word       | subst. word     | subst. null
>   ___________________|___________________|_________________|________________
> ```

Comment: Aha.  `man bash` covers the `:-` usage, but doesn't document the `-` usage.  And I see from the above that they *are* different.  Good to know.  So then, the rest of the line is used as just a literal string (if it's used at all)—i.e. `'||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s'` with no expansions of any kind?

Comment: Whoops, it IS covered after all!  `Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset.`  Thanks very much!

Comment: The table above was taken from the POSIX standard. The original Bourne Shell man page did not document the difference between `:-` and `-` very well although it is hidden in some sentence. It seems that bash copied from the original Bourne Shell man page and introduced a similar hard to understand text.

Comment: Yes, you found the sentence taken from the old Bourne Shell man page!

Comment: Yes—thanks again!  Actually, I'm relieved to know that the crazy-long bash man page IS complete after all; it was worrying to think I could read the whole thing and still be in mystery about certain features.  :)

Comment: BTW: If I remember a recent talk from Steven Bourne correctly, the support for the additional colon was added around 1979.