# Open multiple man pages in less?

Tags: man, less

I've noticed that when running `man command1 command2`, the behavior is: first the man page for `command1` is formatted and displayed in `less`, and then *after* that `less` instance exits (e.g. by pressing `q`), the man page for `command2` is formatted and displayed in a *new* instance of `less`.

**How can I get multiple man pages displayed within the same instance of `less`?**

`less` has many features only applicable when multiple files are open, such as multi-file search, cross-file "marks" for positions, and others.

Comment: If you use Vim's [manpage support](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#%3AMan), then you get the whole tabs/windows/kitchen sink feature set as well.

Comment: @muru, interesting.  With the approach at that linked page, I get `Error detected while processing command line:
E492: Not an editor command: MANPAGER`, but `:help :Man` within Vim shows how to enable the `:Man` command—not quite the same, though....

Comment: the page says "To start using the ":Man" command before any manual page was loaded, source
this script from your startup vimrc file: `runtime ftplugin/man.vim`" O.o

Comment: @muru, I can't make sense of that line at all.  But it appears that patch 7.4.1804 is what added the "manpager" approach.  I'm on Vim 7.2.

Comment: Uh, nope. 7.4.1804 only makes it easier to use vim as manpager. The `:Man` command itself is [far older](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/071d4279d6ab81b7187b48f3a0fc61e587b6db6c/runtime/ftplugin/man.vim#L6). And what's so difficult to understand? You have to load the command before it can be used, that's all.

Comment: @muru, even with that line in `.vimrc`, the following command throws the error in my comment above: `MANPAGER="env MAN_PN=1 vim -M +MANPAGER -" man less`

Comment: That's obviously the settings from 7.4.1804. Why would you use that?

Comment: @muru, okay, so, before 7.4.1804, you can't set it up so that `man somecommand` on the command line will directly wind you up looking at the man page in Vim—right?  But you *can* use the `:Man` command from *inside* older Vims to open man pages.  Or did I miss some way older Vims can be used directly as manpagers?  (I don't see it in the built in `:help` on my Vim.)

Comment: Before 7.4.1804, to use Vim as manpager you would have needed a plugin or some custom setup. The `MANPAGER` command was added to make it possible to use Vim without plugins as the manpager.

Comment: @Wildcard The manual is wrong (or `ftplugin/man.vim` is broken, if you prefer). The `:Man` command exists only if the current `filetype` is `man`. So load `ftplugin/man.vim` and run `:setf man`: then you'll be able to use `:Man`.  That said, perhaps you shouldn't admit in polite conversation that you're still running Vim 7.2 at the end of 2017. :)

Comment: @SatōKatsura, sysadmin here—not a developer.  I work with what's on the thousands of Linux machines I work with.  Some of them have newer Vims, I'm sure—but RHEL 6 default is what I can count on having available.  Thanks for the tip re ftplugin.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I've worked out the answer:

```
mman() { LESSOPEN='|man %s' less -is "$@"; }
```

After running this function definition, running, for example:

```
mman postfix postqueue postsuper
```

will open all three man pages in the `less` pager, each as separate files, accessible with `:n` and `:p` and cross-file searching, etc.

---

If you wish to read up on how this works, I suggest `LESS='+/^INPUT PREPROCESSOR' man less` as a good place to start.  :)

Comment: That's a nice approach.  If you have man-db >= 2.5.0, then you can add `MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING=1` to the internal `man` invocation, and that way you won't lose the usual manual page bold/italic formatting.